# Plugin Sublime Text - Publica arquivos automaticamente em outra pasta

Tags: sublime-text-2

Alguém conhece algum plugin para o Sublime Text 2 que de alguma forma publique os arquivos modificados em uma dada pasta?

Outro aplicativo que tem este recurso é o Dreamweaver.

Answer (score 2):

Eu utilizo um [*build system*](http://sublimetext.info/docs/en/reference/build_systems.html). É rápido, fácil e simples. :)

Eu uso Windows 8, mas o princípio é o mesmo pra outros sistemas operacionais (e há mais detalhes na documentação que eu referenciei acima):

- Crie um arquivo de *build system* específico para o seu projeto (por exemplo, `meuProjeto.sublime-build`) no no diretório `Packages\User` a partir da instalação (no caso do Windows fica em `User\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages\User`).
- Adicione nesse arquivo uma tag de comando para a execução de um arquivo de *script* (no caso do Windows, um arquivo *batch*). Por exemplo:

```batch
{
    "cmd": ["C:\\CAMINHO\\DO\\SCRIPT\\meuProjeto-copiaArquivos.bat"]
}
```

- Então, crie o arquivo de *script* no caminho e com o nome previamente configurados, adicionando os comandos necessários para a cópia dos arquivos do seu projeto.

Eu uso esse esquema para copiar arquivos de projetos Web usando o comando `xcopy` para uma pasta do Wamp Server, e então abrindo automaticamente o Google Chrome em `localhost`:

```batch
@echo off
xcopy /E /Y /A C:\CAMINHO\DO\PROJETO\*.* C:\wamp\www\MeuProjeto\
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" "http://localhost/"
```

Depois provavelmente você precisará reinicializar o Sublime Text, mas o novo *build system* poderá ser selecionado no menu `Tools -> Build System` e executado no menu `Tools -> Build`.